# Magento 2 order shipment tracking details

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipment, shipment-tracking

How to get tracking information from order shipment in magento 2?

Comment: what you want to get from tracking info ?

Comment: All tracking info

Comment: take a look at `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Is it working ? @JitendraPatel

Comment: I will check and update you soon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all tracking details using this code :

```
$tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();

foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {

     echo $track->getTrackNumber(); // Tracking number
     // You can get other details here.

}
```